# Closing gtk application when SWF ends (NPAPI)

Tags: gtk, flash, npapi

Is there a way to know when my flash ends in NPAPI (like a flag). I want to close my application when my flash is done displaying.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An NPAPI plugin ends when the browser hosting it closes, not the other way around. The only way you might be able to do this is to have your SWF notify javascript which then does something akin to window.close()

Comment: Yes. That's exacly what I was expecting. Thank you.

Comment: Used NPN_Evaluate function to handle the javascript with Local shared objects (LSOs) from flash. Worked.