# Embedding Flash in Linux GTK Application - Sandbox Violation

Tags: c, linux, flash, gtk, npapi

I'm embedding a Flash SWF file in a Linux application using the NPAPI. Everything works fine but when the Flash calls "fscommand", I'm getting a security sandbox violation. I tried the program with several Linux distributions and several versions of the Flash Player (9,10,11) but no luck.

Does anybody know if this is a limitation of the Flash Player in Linux platforms?

In this post [Closing gtk application when SWF ends (NPAPI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726487/closing-gtk-application-when-swf-ends-npapi) it seems they have been able to receive Javascript events.

This is the code I'm using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>

//#include "npupp.h"
#include "npapi.h"
#include "npfunctions.h"

//#ifdef __i386__
#define FLASH_PLUGIN_SO "./flash/libflashplayer32.so"
//#else
//#define FLASH_PLUGIN_SO "./flash/libflashplayer64.so"
//#endif

#define PR_TRUE 1
#define PR_FALSE 0

#define WINDOW_XSIZE 1600/2
#define WINDOW_YSIZE 900/2

#define NO_IDENTIFIER       ((NPIdentifier)0)
#define SPECIAL_IDENTIFIER  0x0FEEBBCC
#define SPECIAL_METHOD_NAME "swhxCall"

#define FLASH_REQUEST       "__flash__request"
#define FSCMD           "_DoFSCommand"
#define INVOKE_RESPONSE "<invoke name=\"%s\" returntype=\"javascript\"><arguments><null/></arguments></invoke>"

typedef intptr_t int_val;

void *flash_plugin_handle;

NPNetscapeFuncs browserFuncs;
NPPluginFuncs pluginFuncs;

GtkWidget *main_window;

char* URL;
NPStream * stream;
const char * uagent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13";

NPError (*iNP_Initialize)(NPNetscapeFuncs* bFuncs, NPPluginFuncs* pFuncs);
NPError (*iNP_Shutdown)();
char* (*iNP_GetMIMEDescription)();

// --- Property IDs

static char **np_ids = NULL;
static int_val np_id_count = 0;

static NPIdentifier resolveNPId( const char *id ) {
    int_val i;
    for(i=0;i<np_id_count;i++)
        if( strcmp(np_ids[i],id) == 0 )
            return (NPIdentifier)(i+1);
    if( strcmp(id,SPECIAL_METHOD_NAME) == 0 )
        return (NPIdentifier)SPECIAL_IDENTIFIER;
    return NO_IDENTIFIER;
}

static NPIdentifier addNPId( const char *id ) {
    NPIdentifier newid = resolveNPId(id);
    if( newid == NO_IDENTIFIER ) {
        np_id_count++;
        printf("New npid added: %i == %s\n",np_id_count, id);
        np_ids = realloc(np_ids,np_id_count*sizeof(char*));
        np_ids[np_id_count-1] = strdup(id);
        return (NPIdentifier)np_id_count;
    }
    return newid;
}

static const char *getNPId( NPIdentifier id ) {
    int_val index = ((int_val)id)-1;
    if( index >= 0 && index < np_id_count )
        return np_ids[index];
    if( id == (NPIdentifier)SPECIAL_IDENTIFIER )
        return SPECIAL_METHOD_NAME;
    return NULL;
}

static int matchNPId(NPIdentifier id, const char *str) {
    const char *strid = getNPId(id);
    return ( strid != NULL && strcmp(strid,str) == 0 );
}

void freeNPIds() {
    while( np_id_count )
        free(np_ids[--np_id_count]);
    free(np_ids);
}

static bool NPN_InvokeProc( NPP npp, NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier methodName, const NPVariant *args, uint32_t argCount, NPVariant *result ) ;
static bool NPN_InvokeDefaultProc( NPP npp, NPObject *npobj, const NPVariant *args, uint32_t argCount, NPVariant *result ) ;
static bool NPN_GetPropertyProc( NPP npp, NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier propertyName, NPVariant *result ) ;
static bool NPN_SetPropertyProc( NPP npp, NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier propertyName, const NPVariant *value ) ;
static bool NPN_RemovePropertyProc( NPP npp, NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier propertyName ) ;
static bool NPN_HasPropertyProc( NPP npp, NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier propertyName ) ;
static bool NPN_HasMethodProc( NPP npp, NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier methodName ) ;

static NPObject *NPN_CreateObjectProc( NPP npp, NPClass *aClass );
static NPObject *NPN_RetainObjectProc( NPObject *npobj );

// Window class;
static NPClass __gen_class =
    { NP_CLASS_STRUCT_VERSION
    , (NPAllocateFunctionPtr) malloc
    , (NPDeallocateFunctionPtr) free
    , 0
    , (NPHasMethodFunctionPtr) NPN_HasMethodProc
    , (NPInvokeFunctionPtr) NPN_InvokeProc
    , (NPInvokeDefaultFunctionPtr)NPN_InvokeDefaultProc
    , (NPHasPropertyFunctionPtr) NPN_HasPropertyProc
    , (NPGetPropertyFunctionPtr) NPN_GetPropertyProc
    , (NPSetPropertyFunctionPtr) NPN_SetPropertyProc
    , (NPRemovePropertyFunctionPtr) NPN_RemovePropertyProc
    };
static NPObject __window = { &__gen_class, 1 };
static NPObject __location = { &__gen_class, 1};
static NPObject __top = { &__gen_class, 1 };
static NPObject __top_location = { &__gen_class, 1 };

static void traceObjectOnCall(const char *f, NPObject *o){
    if (o == &__top) printf("DOM object 'top': %s\n",f);
    else if (o == &__window) printf("DOM object 'window': %s\n",f);
    else if (o == &__location) printf("DOM object 'location': %s\n",f);
    else if (o == &__top_location) printf("DOM object 'top.location': %s\n",f);
}

static void checkError(const char* str, NPError err) {
if(err == NPERR_NO_ERROR)
printf("[+] %s: success\n", str);
else
printf("[-] %s: failed (%d)\n", str, err);
fflush (stdout);
}

void* loadFlashPluginSo() {
    void *handle;

    handle = dlopen(FLASH_PLUGIN_SO, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL);
    if(!handle) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] error loading libflasplayer.so: %s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }   
    puts("[+] loaded libflashplayer.so");
    return handle;
}

void* loadSymbol(void *handle, const char *name) {
    char *error;
    void *ret;

    ret = dlsym(handle, name);

    if((error = dlerror()) != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] error loading symbol %s: %s\n", name, error);
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("[+] loaded symbol %s, address: %p\n", name, ret);
    }
    return ret;
}

void loadNPEntryPoints(void *handle) {
    iNP_Initialize=(NPError (*)(NPNetscapeFuncs* bFuncs, NPPluginFuncs* pFuncs))loadSymbol(handle, "NP_Initialize");
    iNP_Shutdown=(NPError (*)())loadSymbol(handle, "NP_Shutdown");
    iNP_GetMIMEDescription = (char*(*)())loadSymbol(handle,"NP_GetMIMEDescription");
}

void printPluginEntrypoints(NPPluginFuncs* pFuncs) {
printf("[*] NPP struct:\n");
printf("\t- NPP_size: %8d\n",pFuncs->size);
printf("\t- NPP_version: %8d\n",pFuncs->version);
printf("\t- NPP_NewProcPtr: %p\n", pFuncs->newp);
printf("\t- NPP_DestroyProcPtr: %p\n", pFuncs->destroy);
printf("\t- NPP_SetWindowProcPtr: %p\n", pFuncs->setwindow);
printf("\t- NPP_NewStreamProcPtr: %p\n", pFuncs->newstream);
printf("\t- NPP_DestroyStreamProcPtr: %p\n", pFuncs->destroystream);
printf("\t- NPP_StreamAsFileProcPtr: %p\n", pFuncs->asfile);
printf("\t- NPP_WriteReadyProcPtr: %p\n", pFuncs->writeready);
printf("\t- NPP_WriteProcPtr: %p\n", pFuncs->write);
printf("\t- NPP_PrintProcPtr: %p\n", pFuncs->print);
printf("\t- NPP_HandleEventProcPtr: %p\n", pFuncs->event);
printf("\t- NPP_URLNotifyProcPtr: %p\n", pFuncs->urlnotify);
printf("\t- javaClass: %p\n", pFuncs->javaClass);
printf("\t- NPP_GetValueProcPtr: %p\n", pFuncs->getvalue);
printf("\t- NPP_SetValueProcPtr: %p\n", pFuncs->setvalue);
}

NPError NPN_SetValueProc(NPP instance, NPPVariable variable, void *value)
{
    switch(variable) {
        case NPPVpluginWindowBool:
            printf( "NPPVpluginWindowBool - %p\n", value);
            break;
        default:
            printf( "SetValue %i\n", variable );
            break;
    }
    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

NPError NPN_GetValueProc(NPP instance, NPNVariable variable, void *ret_value) {

printf("[D] NPN_GetValueProc instance:%p, variable:%d, abi_mask:%d\n", instance, variable, 0);

switch (variable) {
    case NPNVSupportsXEmbedBool:
        *((int*)ret_value)= PR_TRUE;
        break;
    case NPNVToolkit:
        *((int*)ret_value)= NPNVGtk2;
        break;
    case NPNVnetscapeWindow:
        *((int*)ret_value)= PR_TRUE;
        break;
    default:
        *((int*)ret_value)=PR_FALSE;
        break;
    }
    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

const char* NPN_UserAgentProc(NPP instance) {
    return uagent;
}

static void Status_( NPP instance, const char* message ) {
    printf( "Status\n" );
}

uint32_t MemFlush( uint32_t size ) {
    return 0;
}

void ReloadPlugins( NPBool reloadPages ) {
}

void * GetJavaEnv(void) {
    return NULL;
}

void * GetJavaPeer( NPP instance ) {
    return NULL;
}

NPIdentifier NPN_GetStringIdentifierProc(const NPUTF8* name) {
    return addNPId(name);
}

void GetStringIdentifiers( const NPUTF8 **names, int32_t nameCount, NPIdentifier *identifiers ) {
}

NPIdentifier GetIntIdentifier( int32_t intid ) {
    return NO_IDENTIFIER;
}

bool IdentifierIsString( NPIdentifier id ) {
    return getNPId(id) != NULL;
}

NPUTF8* UTF8FromIdentifier( NPIdentifier identifier ) {
    const char *result = getNPId(identifier);
    return result ? strdup(result) : NULL;
}

int32_t IntFromIdentifier( NPIdentifier id ) {
    return 0;
}

static gboolean plug_removed_cb (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
    printf("[!] plug_removed_cb\n");
    return TRUE;
}

static void socket_unrealize_cb(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
    printf("[!] socket_unrealize_cb\n");
}

static NPWindow * npwindow_construct (GtkWidget *widget) {
    NPWindow *npwindow;
    NPSetWindowCallbackStruct *ws_info = NULL;

    GdkWindow *parent_win = widget->window;

    GtkWidget *socketWidget = gtk_socket_new();
    gtk_widget_set_parent_window(socketWidget, parent_win);

    g_signal_connect(socketWidget, "plug_removed", G_CALLBACK(plug_removed_cb), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(socketWidget, "unrealize", G_CALLBACK(socket_unrealize_cb), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(socketWidget, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroyed), &socketWidget);

    gpointer user_data = NULL;
    gdk_window_get_user_data(parent_win, &user_data);

    GtkContainer *container = GTK_CONTAINER(user_data);
    gtk_container_add(container, socketWidget);
    gtk_widget_realize(socketWidget);

    GtkAllocation new_allocation;
    new_allocation.x = 0;
    new_allocation.y = 0;
    new_allocation.width = WINDOW_XSIZE;
    new_allocation.height = WINDOW_YSIZE;
    gtk_widget_size_allocate(socketWidget, &new_allocation);

    gtk_widget_show(socketWidget);
    gdk_flush();

    GdkNativeWindow ww = gtk_socket_get_id(GTK_SOCKET(socketWidget));
    GdkWindow *w = gdk_window_lookup(ww);

    npwindow = (NPWindow*) malloc (sizeof (NPWindow));
    npwindow->window = (void*)(unsigned long)ww;
    npwindow->x = 0;
    npwindow->y = 0;
    npwindow->width = WINDOW_XSIZE;
    npwindow->height = WINDOW_YSIZE;

    ws_info = (NPSetWindowCallbackStruct*) malloc(sizeof (NPSetWindowCallbackStruct));
    ws_info->type = NP_SETWINDOW;
    ws_info->display = GDK_WINDOW_XDISPLAY(w);
    ws_info->colormap = GDK_COLORMAP_XCOLORMAP(gdk_drawable_get_colormap(w));
    GdkVisual* gdkVisual = gdk_drawable_get_visual(w);
    ws_info->visual = GDK_VISUAL_XVISUAL(gdkVisual);
    ws_info->depth = gdkVisual->depth;

    npwindow->ws_info = ws_info;
    npwindow->type = NPWindowTypeWindow;

    return npwindow;
}

static NPStream * npstream_construct() {
    NPStream *stream = (NPStream *) malloc(sizeof(NPStream));

    stream->url=strdup(URL);
    stream->ndata = 0;
    stream->end = 99782;
    stream->lastmodified= 1201822722;
    stream->notifyData = 0x00000000;
    stream->headers = (char*)malloc(200);

    return stream;
}

bool NPN_InvokeProc( NPP npp, NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier npid, const NPVariant *args, uint32_t argCount, NPVariant *result ) {

    traceObjectOnCall(__FUNCTION__,npobj);

    if( matchNPId(npid,FLASH_REQUEST) && argCount == 1 && args[0].type == NPVariantType_String ) {
        return 1;
    }
    if( matchNPId(npid,FLASH_REQUEST) && argCount == 3 &&
        args[0].type == NPVariantType_String &&
        args[1].type == NPVariantType_String &&
        args[2].type == NPVariantType_String
    ) {
        return 1;
    }

    if( matchNPId(npid,"_DoFSCommand") && argCount == 2 && args[0].type == NPVariantType_String && args[1].type == NPVariantType_String ) {
        printf("[D] FSCOMMAND\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if( npobj == &__top_location ) {
        if( matchNPId(npid,"toString") ) {
            result->type = NPVariantType_String;
            // "chrome://global/content/console.xul" is what Firefox returns for 'top.location.toString()';
            result->value.stringValue.UTF8Characters = strdup("chrome://global/content/console.xul");
            result->value.stringValue.UTF8Length = (int)strlen(result->value.stringValue.UTF8Characters);
            printf("[D] Returned %s\n", result->value.stringValue.UTF8Characters);
        }
        return 1;
    }
    //On OSX, Flash retreives locations by injected functions:
    if( matchNPId(npid,"__flash_getWindowLocation") ) {
        // return the location object:
        result->type = NPVariantType_Object;
        result->value.objectValue = &__location;
        NPN_RetainObjectProc(&__location);
        return 1;
    }
    if( matchNPId(npid,"__flash_getTopLocation") ) {
        // return the top_location object:
        result->type = NPVariantType_Object;
        result->value.objectValue = &__top_location;
        NPN_RetainObjectProc(&__top_location);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static bool NPN_InvokeDefaultProc( NPP npp, NPObject *npobj, const NPVariant *args, uint32_t argCount, NPVariant *result ) {
    return 0;
}

static bool NPN_GetPropertyProc( NPP npp, NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier npid, NPVariant *result ) {

    if (npobj == &__window) {
        if( matchNPId(npid,"location") ) {
            result->type = NPVariantType_Object;
            result->value.objectValue = &__location;
            NPN_RetainObjectProc(&__location);
            return 1;
        }
        if( matchNPId(npid,"top") ) {
            result->type = NPVariantType_Object;
            result->value.objectValue = &__top;
            NPN_RetainObjectProc(&__top);
            return 1;
        }
    } else if (npobj == &__top) {
        if ( matchNPId(npid,"location") ) {
            result->type = NPVariantType_Object;
            result->value.objectValue = &__top_location;
            NPN_RetainObjectProc(&__top_location);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

static bool NPN_SetPropertyProc( NPP npp, NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier propertyName, const NPVariant *value ) {
    return 0;
}

static bool NPN_RemovePropertyProc( NPP npp, NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier propertyName ) {
    return 0;
}

static bool NPN_HasPropertyProc( NPP npp, NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier propertyName ) {
    return 0;
}

static bool NPN_HasMethodProc( NPP npp, NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier methodName ) {
    return 0;
}

static int unescape( char *str, int *ssize ) {
    int k = 0, esc = 0;
    // UNESCAPE the string
    while( k < *ssize ) {
        if( !esc ) {
            if( str[k++] == '\\' )
                esc = 1;
        } else {
            char c;
            switch( str[k] ) {
            case '"': c = '"'; break;
            case '\\': c = '\\'; break;
            case 'r': c = '\r'; break;
            case 'n': c = '\n'; break;
            case 't': c = '\t'; break;
            default:
                return 0;
            }
            (*ssize)--;
            memcpy(str+k,str+k+1,*ssize-k);
            str[k-1] = c;
            esc = 0;
        }
    }
    str[*ssize] = 0;
    return 1;
}

static const char *end_of_string( const char *send ) {
    int esc = 0;
    while( *send ) {
        switch( *send ) {
        case '"':
            if( !esc )
                return send;
            esc = 0;
            break;
        case '\\':
            esc = !esc;
            break;
        default:
            esc = 0;
            break;
        }
        send++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

#define JS_CALL_START "try { __flash__toXML("
#define JS_RESULT_START "var __flash_temp = \""

bool Evaluate( NPP npp, NPObject *npobj, NPString *script, NPVariant *result ) {
    printf( "Evaluate %s\n", script->UTF8Characters );
    if( memcmp(script->UTF8Characters,JS_CALL_START,strlen(JS_CALL_START)) == 0 ) {
        const char *p = script->UTF8Characters + strlen(JS_CALL_START);
        const char *s = p;
        const char *send;
        while( *s && *s != '(' )
            s++;
        if( !*s || s[1] != '"' )
            return 0;
        s += 2;
        send = end_of_string(s);
        if( send == NULL || send[1] != ')' )
            return 0;
        {
            int isize = (int)(s - p) - 2;
            int ssize = (int)(send - s);
            char *ident = (char*)malloc(isize+1);
            char *str = (char*)malloc(ssize+1);
            memcpy(ident,p,isize);
            memcpy(str,s,ssize);
            ident[isize] = 0;
            if( !unescape(str,&ssize) ) {
                free(ident);
                free(str);
                return 0;
            }
            // CALLBACK
            {               
                printf("CALLBACK\n");
                int size = 0;
                const char *res = "callback";
                free(ident);
                free(str);
                if( res == NULL )
                    return 0;
                result->type = NPVariantType_String;
                result->value.stringValue.UTF8Characters = strdup(res);
                result->value.stringValue.UTF8Length = size;
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if( memcmp(script->UTF8Characters,JS_RESULT_START,strlen(JS_RESULT_START)) == 0 ) {
        const char *s = script->UTF8Characters + strlen(JS_RESULT_START);
        const char *send = end_of_string(s);
        char *str;
        int ssize;
        if( send == NULL || send[1] != ';' )
            return 0;
        ssize = (int)(send - s);
        str = (char*)malloc(ssize+1);
        memcpy(str,s,ssize);
        if( !unescape(str,&ssize) ) {
            free(str);
            return 0;
        }
        result->type = NPVariantType_String;
        result->value.stringValue.UTF8Characters = str;
        result->value.stringValue.UTF8Length = ssize;
        return 1;
    }
    result->type = NPVariantType_Void;
    return 1;
}

void NPN_ReleaseObjectProc(NPObject *npobj) {
    if( npobj == NULL )
        return;
    npobj->referenceCount--;
    if( npobj->referenceCount != 0 )
        return;
    if( npobj->_class->deallocate ) {
        npobj->_class->deallocate(npobj);
        return;
    }
    if( npobj->_class->invalidate )
        npobj->_class->invalidate(npobj);
    free(npobj);
}

NPObject* NPN_CreateObjectProc(NPP npp, NPClass *aClass) {
    NPObject *o;
    if( aClass->allocate )
        o = aClass->allocate(npp,aClass);
    else
        o = (NPObject*)malloc(sizeof(NPObject));
    o->_class = aClass;
    o->referenceCount = 1;
    return o;
}

NPObject* NPN_RetainObjectProc(NPObject *npobj) {
    if( npobj == NULL )
        return NULL;
    npobj->referenceCount++;
    return npobj;
}

void NPN_ReleaseVariantValueProc(NPVariant *variant) {
    //printf("ReleaseVariantValueProc\n");
    switch( variant->type ) {
        case NPVariantType_Null:
        case NPVariantType_Void:
            break;
        case NPVariantType_String:
            free( (char*)variant->value.stringValue.UTF8Characters );
            variant->type = NPVariantType_Void;
            break;
        case NPVariantType_Object:
            NPN_ReleaseObjectProc(variant->value.objectValue);
            variant->type = NPVariantType_Void;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void SetException( NPObject *npobj, const NPUTF8 *message ) {
    printf("SetException %s\n",message);
}

NPError NPN_GetURLNotifyProc(NPP instance, const char* url, const char* window, void* notifyData) {
    printf("[D] NPN_GetURLNotifyProc:%p, url: %s, window: %s\n", instance, url, window);
    if (window && strlen(window)==6 && memcmp("_blank",window,6)==0) {
        //system_launch_url(url);
        pluginFuncs.urlnotify(instance,url,NPRES_DONE,notifyData);
    } else if( memcmp(url,"javascript:",11) == 0 ) {
        NPStream s;
        uint16_t stype;
        int success;
        memset(&s,0,sizeof(NPStream));
        s.url = strdup(url);
        success = (pluginFuncs.newstream(instance,"text/html",&s,0,&stype) == NPERR_NO_ERROR);      
        if( success ) {
            int pos = 0;
            int size;
            char buf[256];
            sprintf(buf,"%X__flashplugin_unique__",(int_val)instance);
            size = (int)strlen(buf);
            s.end = size;
            while( pos < size ) {
                int len = pluginFuncs.writeready(instance,&s);
                if( len <= 0 )
                    break;
                if( len > size - pos )
                    len = size - pos;
                len = pluginFuncs.write(instance,&s,pos,len,buf+pos);
                if( len <= 0 )
                    break;
                pos += len;
            }
            success = (pos == size);
        }
        pluginFuncs.urlnotify(instance,url,success?NPRES_DONE:NPRES_NETWORK_ERR,notifyData);
        pluginFuncs.destroystream(instance,&s,NPRES_DONE);
        free((void*)s.url);
    } else {

        NPStream stream;
        uint16_t stype;// = NP_NORMAL;

        memset(&stream,0,sizeof(NPStream));
        stream.url = strdup(url);
        stream.notifyData = notifyData;

        pluginFuncs.newstream(instance,"application/x-shockwave-flash",&stream, 0, &stype);
        //fprintf(stderr, "NPP: %p URL: %s\n", instance, url);

        FILE *pp;
        char buffer[8192];
        pp = fopen(url,"rb");
        int len;

        while((len=fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), pp)) != 0) {
            pluginFuncs.writeready(instance, &stream);
            pluginFuncs.write(instance, &stream, 0, len, buffer);
        }

        fclose(pp);
        pluginFuncs.destroystream(instance, &stream, NPRES_DONE);

        free((void*)stream.url);
        //pluginFuncs.urlnotify(instance, url, NPRES_DONE, notifyData);
    }

    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

NPError NPN_GetURL( NPP instance, const char* url, const char* target ) {
    printf( "GetURL %s\n", url );
    if (target && strlen(target)==6 && memcmp("_blank",target,6)==0) {
        //system_launch_url(url);
        return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
    }
    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

NPError NPN_PostURLNotify( NPP instance, const char* url, const char* target, uint32_t len, const char* buf, NPBool file, void* notifyData) {
    printf( "PostURLNotify (url) %s (target) %s (buf) %s[%d] (file) %i (nd) %p\n", url, target,  buf, len, file, notifyData);
    //url_process(instance,url,buf,len,notifyData);
    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

NPError NPN_PostURL( NPP instance, const char* url, const char* target, uint32_t len, const char* buf, NPBool file ) {
    printf( "PostURL" );
    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

NPError NPN_RequestRead(NPStream* stream, NPByteRange* range_list) {
    printf("[D] NPN_RequestRead\n");
        return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

NPError NewStream( NPP instance, NPMIMEType type, const char* target, NPStream** stream ) {
    printf( "NewStream\n" );
    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

int32_t Write( NPP instance, NPStream* stream, int32_t len, void* buffer ) {
    printf( "Write\n" );
    return 0;
}

NPError DestroyStream( NPP instance, NPStream* stream, NPReason reason ) {
    printf( "DestroyStream\n" );
    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

void _InvalidateRect( NPP instance, NPRect *invalidRect ) {
    printf( "InvalidateRect\n" );

}

void InvalidateRegion( NPP instance, NPRegion invalidRegion ) {
    printf( "InvalidateRegion\n" );
}

void ForceRedraw( NPP instance ) {
    printf( "ForceRedraw\n" );
}

void initNPNetscapeFuncs(NPNetscapeFuncs *bFuncs) {
    int i=0;

    for(i=1; i<sizeof(*bFuncs)/sizeof(ssize_t); i++)
    *(((ssize_t*)bFuncs)+i)=i+1000;

bFuncs->geturl=NPN_GetURL;
bFuncs->posturl=NPN_PostURL;
bFuncs->requestread=NPN_RequestRead;
bFuncs->newstream=NewStream;
bFuncs->write=Write;
bFuncs->destroystream=DestroyStream;
bFuncs->status=Status_;
bFuncs->uagent=NPN_UserAgentProc;
bFuncs->memalloc=malloc;
bFuncs->memfree=free;
bFuncs->memflush=MemFlush;
bFuncs->reloadplugins=ReloadPlugins;
bFuncs->getJavaEnv=GetJavaEnv;
bFuncs->getJavaPeer=GetJavaPeer;
bFuncs->geturlnotify=NPN_GetURLNotifyProc;
bFuncs->posturlnotify=NPN_PostURLNotify;
bFuncs->getvalue=NPN_GetValueProc;
bFuncs->setvalue=NPN_SetValueProc;
bFuncs->invalidaterect=_InvalidateRect;
bFuncs->invalidateregion=InvalidateRegion;
bFuncs->forceredraw=ForceRedraw;
bFuncs->getstringidentifier=NPN_GetStringIdentifierProc;
bFuncs->getstringidentifiers=GetStringIdentifiers;
bFuncs->getintidentifier=GetIntIdentifier;
bFuncs->identifierisstring=IdentifierIsString;
bFuncs->utf8fromidentifier=UTF8FromIdentifier;
bFuncs->intfromidentifier=IntFromIdentifier;
bFuncs->createobject=NPN_CreateObjectProc;
bFuncs->retainobject=NPN_RetainObjectProc;
bFuncs->releaseobject=NPN_ReleaseObjectProc;
bFuncs->invoke=NPN_InvokeProc;
bFuncs->invokeDefault=NPN_InvokeDefaultProc;
bFuncs->evaluate=Evaluate;
bFuncs->getproperty=NPN_GetPropertyProc;
bFuncs->setproperty=NPN_SetPropertyProc;
bFuncs->removeproperty=NPN_RemovePropertyProc;
bFuncs->hasproperty=NPN_HasPropertyProc;
bFuncs->hasmethod=NPN_HasMethodProc;
bFuncs->releasevariantvalue=NPN_ReleaseVariantValueProc;
bFuncs->setexception=SetException;

    bFuncs->size= sizeof(bFuncs);
//  bFuncs->version=(NP_VERSION_MAJOR << 8) + NP_VERSION_MINOR;
    bFuncs->version=20;
}

static void destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
    gtk_main_quit ();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("[-] Usage: %s <swfuri>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    URL = argv[1];

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    main_window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_set_usize (main_window, WINDOW_XSIZE, WINDOW_YSIZE);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (main_window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);
    gtk_widget_realize(main_window);
    //gtk_window_fullscreen((GtkWindow *)main_window);
    gtk_widget_show_all(main_window);

    printf("[+] created GTK widget\n");

    flash_plugin_handle = loadFlashPluginSo();

    loadNPEntryPoints(flash_plugin_handle);
    printf("[+] initialized flash plugin entry points\n");

    initNPNetscapeFuncs(&browserFuncs);
    printf("[+] initialized browser functions\n");

    checkError("NP_Initialize", iNP_Initialize(&browserFuncs, &pluginFuncs));

    printPluginEntrypoints(&pluginFuncs);

    printBrowserEntrypoints(&browserFuncs);

    NPWindow *npwin = npwindow_construct(main_window);
    printf("[+] created NPWindow widget\n");

    NPP_t *instancep = (NPP_t *) malloc(sizeof(NPP_t));
    memset(instancep,0,sizeof(sizeof(NPP_t)));
    NPP instance = instancep;

    NPSavedData* saved = (NPSavedData*) malloc(sizeof(NPSavedData));
    memset(saved,0,sizeof(sizeof(NPSavedData)));

    stream = npstream_construct();
    uint16_t stype;
    NPObject object;


    char *xargv[]= {"allowscriptaccess", "quality", "wmode"};
    char *xargm[]= {"always", "best", "direct"};


    checkError("NPN_New", pluginFuncs.newp("application/x-shockwave-flash", instance, NP_EMBED, 3, xargv, xargm, 0));
    checkError("NPN_GetValue NPPVpluginScriptableNPObject", pluginFuncs.getvalue(instance, NPPVpluginScriptableNPObject, &object));

    checkError("NPN_SetWindow", pluginFuncs.setwindow(instance, npwin));
    checkError("NPN_NewStream", pluginFuncs.newstream(instance, "application/x-shockwave-flash", stream, 0, &stype));

    FILE *pp;
    char buffer[8192];
    pp = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
    int len;
    while((len=fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), pp)) != 0) {
        pluginFuncs.writeready(instance, stream);
        pluginFuncs.write(instance, stream, 0, len, buffer);
    }
    fclose(pp);

    checkError("NPN_DestroyStream",pluginFuncs.destroystream(instance, stream, NPRES_DONE));

    free(stream);
    gtk_main();

    checkError("NPN_Destroy",pluginFuncs.destroy(instance, &saved));
    checkError("NP_Shutdown", iNP_Shutdown());

    dlclose(flash_plugin_handle);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer your question, but your source code above is well written and extremely helpful for embedding Netscape plugins in GTK without using a browser component (gtkmozembed is being withdrawn and webkit is not reliable for Flash hosting). I wonder if you could make this code available under an open source license for me and others to use?

Comment: I made the code available under MIT license here: 
https://github.com/idaunis/simple-linux-flash-embed

Comment: Thanks for making it open source!